# How to add a new column with the date of the first delivery attempt based on multiple codes in a temporary table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, temp-tables

I have the following table (**Table_A**) where the SHIP_DELIVERED_DATE column contains the date when the order was delivered to the client.
Now I want to add a new column, to contain the date of the first attempt to deliver. This data comes from another table which contains all the codes ([ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER]), for each carrier and reference_id.

**TABLE_A:**

| ORDER_NR | SHIP_REFERENCE | SHIP_COMPANY | SHIP_METHOD | SHIP_COUNTRY | SHIP_STATUS_CODE | SHIP_DATE | SHIP_DELIVERED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SE2303903 | CXEXP3206180 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 10/11/2022 15:35:50 | 16/11/2022 11:33:12 |
| SE2300468 | CXEXP3203508 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 09/11/2022 15:28:48 | 17/11/2022 09:44:27 |
| SE2297858 | CXEXP3200812 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 08/11/2022 14:35:44 | 17/11/2022 09:52:18 |
| SE2289308 | CXEXP3192793 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 04/11/2022 15:38:31 | 10/11/2022 10:15:56 |
| SE2285503 | CXEXP3188494 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 02/11/2022 15:40:23 | 15/11/2022 09:41:02 |

**Table [ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER]** which contains all the codes for each carrier and reference_id (Ship_Reference=CXEXP3206180 as an example):

NOTE:

- EMH - First Attempt to deliver
- EMI - Delivery accomplished

The other codes are not important for this matter

| REFERENCE_ID | CARRIER_ID | CARRIER_NAME | STATUS_CARRIER_ID | STATUS_CARRIER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CXEXP3206180 | DA663004597PT | CTT_CONTINENTE | EMW | 11/11/2022 15:43:33 |
| CXEXP3206180 | DA663004597PT | CTT_CONTINENTE | EMB | 11/11/2022 06:50:52 |
| CXEXP3206180 | DA663004597PT | CTT_CONTINENTE | EMZ | 11/11/2022 09:08:53 |
| CXEXP3206180 | DA663004597PT | CTT_CONTINENTE | EMI | 16/11/2022 11:33:12 |
| CXEXP3206180 | DA663004597PT | CTT_CONTINENTE | EMH | 11/11/2022 11:55:11 |
| CXEXP3206180 | DA663004597PT | CTT_CONTINENTE | EMO | 10/11/2022 15:11:50 |

I have then created this temp table (**Table_B**) with only the first attempt to deliver date for each carrier:

```
--temporary table to hold the first attempt to deliver:

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #first_attempt_to_deliver
    SELECT
    REFERENCE_ID
    ,MIN(STATUS_CARRIER_DATE) AS STATUS_CARRIER_DATE
    INTO #first_attempt_to_deliver
    FROM [WARS].[cust].[ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER] stat WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE STATUS_CARRIER_ID IN ('EMH','01','EMW','07','16','8','39')
    GROUP BY 
    REFERENCE_ID
```

But I've noticed that different carriers can use the same SHIP_REFERENCE, because when I run this code I get many entries where count(*)>1:

```
SELECT wars.SHIP_REFERENCE, count(*) AS Entries
FROM WARS.CUST.ORDER_CAB wars with (nolock)
INNER JOIN #first_attempt_to_deliver fatd with (nolock)
ON fatd.REFERENCE_ID=wars.SHIP_REFERENCE
GROUP BY wars.SHIP_REFERENCE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

so maybe I can't omit the columns CARRIER_ID and CARRIER_NAME and will also need to group by these columns. I'm wondering how will I be able to do the INNER JOIN to ensure I can add this new column on table_A with the correct first attempt to deliver for every row.

The desired result would be:

**TABLE_A +new column with first attempt date per carrier:**

| ORDER_NR | SHIP_REFERENCE | SHIP_COMPANY | SHIP_METHOD | SHIP_COUNTRY | SHIP_STATUS_CODE | SHIP_DATE | SHIP_DELIVERED_DATE | FIRST_ATTEMPT_TO_DELIVER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SE2303903 | CXEXP3206180 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 10/11/2022 15:35:50 | 16/11/2022 11:33:12 | 11/11/2022 11:55:11 |
| SE2300468 | CXEXP3203508 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 09/11/2022 15:28:48 | 17/11/2022 09:44:27 |  |
| SE2297858 | CXEXP3200812 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 08/11/2022 14:35:44 | 17/11/2022 09:52:18 |  |
| SE2289308 | CXEXP3192793 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 04/11/2022 15:38:31 | 10/11/2022 10:15:56 |  |
| SE2285503 | CXEXP3188494 | CTT_CONTINENTE | HOME | PT | EMI | 02/11/2022 15:40:23 | 15/11/2022 09:41:02 |  |

Since EMH is the first attempt to deliver, this should be the outcome when joining table_A and table_B (please note I have only filled in with the first attempt to deliver date from CXEXP3206180, as an example, but every row should be filled in accordingly).

Comment: When you create first_attempt_to_deliver, why do you need group by STATUS_CARRIER_ID ? If you omit it, won't you get the first attempt per order?

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same, in fact, as you are potentially only joining on the `REFERENCE_ID` then you probably don't need to group by carrier either. And you don't need `DISTINCT` as you are grouping the data.

Comment: @siggemannen it makes sense to omit it, but I still have a problem. The same REFERENCE_ID can be related with different carriers, so I can't do INNER JOIN only by the REFERENCE_ID. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: @AlanSchofield the problem is that I can't just use the REFERENCE_ID to do the INNER JOIN, since the same REFERENCE_ID can be related with different carriers. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: If you update, please get rid of images, and put the data into a markdown table

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood completely but this will give you the first Row from `ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER` for each `REFERENCE_ID`.

```
SELECT 
    REFERENCE_ID
    ,CARRIER_ID
    ,STATUS_CARRIER_ID
    ,STATUS_CARRIER_DATE
INTO #first_attempt_to_deliver
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT
            REFERENCE_ID
            ,CARRIER_ID
            ,STATUS_CARRIER_ID
            ,STATUS_CARRIER_DATE
            , RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REFERENCE_ID ORDER BY STATUS_CARRIER_DATE)
        FROM [WARS].[cust].[ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER] stat WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE STATUS_CARRIER_ID IN ('EMH','01','EMW','07','16','8','39')
        ) x 
        WHERE RowN = 1
```

If this does not help, then please add some sample data (as text) and the expected results for the temp table. Or better still use something like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to create a sample input table and then share you expected output.

---

Edit after update from OP

---

It's still not clear if you want to show the 1st attempt per `REFERENCE_ID` regardless of the carrier, or the 1st attempt for each carrier?

The answer above gives you the 1st attempt for each `REFERENCE_ID`. It will only give 1 result per `REFERENCE_ID` so you can join on just the  `REFERENCE_ID` column.

If you need each carrier's first attempt then change the `RowN` line to

```
, RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REFERENCE_ID, CARRIER_ID ORDER BY STATUS_CARRIER_DATE)
```

Now the query will give 1 row per Reference **and** Carrier so you can join to your main table on both these columns.

Comment: I've edited the question so it gets clearer.

Comment: I'll update the answer as I'm still not sure exactly what you want, the sample data does not really have enough variety and you don't show the expected results based on the sample data. The update gives you a few options so hopefully one of them will match your needs.